# Error 404 not found using Insomnia and SpringBoot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, insomnia

Hi I'm learning SpringBoot and I'm trying to make a simple Microservice using Postgresql and SpringBoot, when I make a request (`GET` in this case) from Insomnia I get this response body:

```json
{
  "timestamp": "2023-08-22T16:25:43.756+00:00",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/postgres/all"
}
```

This is my method:

```java
@Override
public List<Person> selectAll() {
    String query = "SELECT * FROM PERSON";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Person.class));
}
```

This is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/postgres")
public class PersonController {

    private AppService appService;


    @GetMapping(value = ("/all"), produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<List<Person>> selectAll() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(appService.selectAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = ("/ins"), produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<Person> insert(@RequestBody Person person) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(appService.insert(person), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is my connection:

```java
@Configuration
public class Connect {
    @Value("postgres")
    String username;

    @Value("postgres")
    String password;

    @Value("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres")
    String url;

    public DataSource postgresConfig() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);

        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

EDIT
This is my request using insomnia

[image]

Comment: Please, put your *request* in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the question, thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you sure that your application is running on port `8080`?

Comment: @DiegoBorba yes